# Easy way to share C/C++ data with Ruby?

Tags: c++, ruby

I have a C++ project from which I'd like to share some basic read-only constants with Ruby. I'd like to define the values in *one place*, such that if the values change they'd be reflected in both Ruby and C++ (after a recompile).

Ideally it would support various basic data types (`std::vector<int>, std::map<int>`, but I think I could get by with just sharing integer values (`const int mysharedval = 1;`)

I've thought of three approaches approaches, but all of them seem a bit too heavy for what I'd like:

1. Wrap a C++ library with Ruby using `extconf.rb`. This seems to require a fairly high amount of boilerplate on both C++ and Ruby sides to get them working together.
2. Storing values in a JSON file that's read from both C++ and Ruby. This adds a dependency on JSON to the C++ and would require code to translate the JSON values into C++ data types.
3. Placing special comments inside C++ header files and manually parsing the file with Ruby to find the values. This is pretty ugly as it would require me to write some kind of basic parser, but once written it would probably be reasonably re-usable.

Is there a simpler option I'm overlooking outside of the above that might be appropriate?

Comment: I really like #2.  Put it in some sort of globals.json file, include the json lib in C++ (or roll out your own solution).  I don't know of an easier way, let alone a way to share vectors and matrices as full types.

Comment: @Bango Yeah, I'm definitely leaning towards #2. Just wasn't sure if I was being crazy and there was something obvious I could do without too much "glue code".

Comment: Search for "ruby c++ bindings"

Comment: @nwp Isn't that option #1?

Comment: @aardvarkk Maybe. A library is supposed to minimize the boiler plate though, so you might want to pick a different library if your complaint is the boiler plate.

Comment: Library is supposed to create the glue for you, minimizing how sticky your hands have to get.  JSON in this case is a light glue for storing string objects, but you have to get your fingers a little sticky if you want them to become C++ types, which is also coincidentally the minimal stickiness of any option I can think of.

Comment: IMHO, this problem better to solve with a code generator.

Comment: Yeah. After spending some time trying to get a map and vector type working, I ended up writing a shell script to generate both a C++ header file and a Ruby file instead. Although my first solution was fun and quirky, the second is probably more realistic. I will add another answer showing that shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final approach was to create a `zsh` shell script that generated code for Ruby and C++ separately. It contained all shared values and was triggered on a code build to ensure that no inconsistencies appeared between the C++ and Ruby code. If anybody's interested in the code, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

OK -- after a lot of experimentation I came up with the following hack! And a pretty epic hack, if you ask me!

It will allow me to define enum types and integers in a **single common file** shared by both Ruby and C++. SharedTypes.h is both valid Ruby and C++!

**SharedTypes.h**

```
#if 0
%q|
#else
enum MyEnum {
#endif
#if 0
|
#else
#endif

FOO = 0,
BAR = 1

#if 0
%q|
#else
};
#endif
#if 0
|
#else
#endif
```

So... how does it work? `#` denotes a line comment in Ruby, so Ruby sees the following:

```
%q|
#else
enum MyEnum {
#endif
#if 0
|

FOO = 0,
BAR = 1

%q|
#else
};
#endif
#if 0
|
```

The `%q` operator defines a multi-line string in Ruby using a custom delimiter of `|`. It doesn't have to be `|`, but I chose something I wasn't going to use in the C++ code. The `#` symbols inside the string are treated as a part of the string, so they're effectively ignored.

We do nothing with these strings, so really all Ruby sees is: `FOO = 0, BAR = 1`, which gives us access to the constants. A Ruby script that wants access to the values can just be like this:

**test.rb**

```
load 'SharedTypes.h'
puts FOO
```

From the C++ side, the `#if`, `#else` and `#end` are preprocessor directives. Since we say `#if 0`, C++ ignores everything between that point and the `#else`. Inside the `#else`, we have code that will only be "seen" by the C++ side. So we can define our `enum` type there. The second block just adds the final `};` to finish the enum. So the C++ perspective is like this after preprocessing stage:

```
enum MyEnum {
  FOO = 0,
  BAR = 1
};
```

Now on the C++ side, we just have:

**test.cpp**

```
#include "SharedTypes.h"
MyEnum test = FOO;
```

Magic.

Hack the planet!

**Note:** I haven't been able to make it work with `std::map` and a Ruby hash yet, but I'd love for somebody to get something like that going! Or `std::vector` and a Ruby array!

Comment: While this works, it's proably too clever by half. Since C++ often involves a build process involving something akin to a `Makefile`, and since you're using Ruby, it'd make more sense for your Ruby code to consume some kind of config file, JSON perhaps, and emit a `.h` or `.cpp` file that handles the definitions. That way one change to your JSON impacts both code-bases properly, no need to do any fancy `#ifdef` junk.

Comment: @tadman Per your suggestion I ended up writing a shell script to generate a C++ header file and a Ruby script containing the constants. That way it was much easier to make it work with arbitrary types. I'll paste the contents of that script as another answer.